# Hydra: Use `# @package _global_` only on a part of a file

Tags: python, fb-hydra

I would like to use the `# @package _global_` directive only on a specific part of my config. E.g. here I want my datamodule to be able to override an attribute of the trainer.
Is there any way to do that?

Things I tried:

1. Using `# @package _global_` at the beginning but I don't want to change the file `default.yaml` (it's imported by other files).
2. Using `trainer@_global_`
3. Using `/trainer`
4. Using `_self_@_global_` (but it seems that it's not allowed and would apply all the rest of the config to `_global_`).

Tree:

```
conf
├── config.yaml
├── datamodule
│   ├── default.yaml
│   └── my_datamodule.yaml
└── trainer
    └── single_gpu.yaml
```

`conf/datamodule/default.yaml`

```
n_train_samples: null
```

`conf/datamodule/my_datamodule.yaml`

```
defaults:
  - default
  - _self_

batch_size: 32

# @package _global_
trainer:
    val_check_interval: 99999
```

---

**Expected behaviour**:
datamodule:
n_train_samples: null
batch_size: 32
trainer:
val_check_interval: 99999
gpus: 1

**Actual behaviour**:
datamodule:
n_train_samples: null
batch_size: 32
trainer:
val_check_interval: 99999999999999999
trainer:
gpus: 1

Comment: Currently there is no way to control the package in such a granular way. There are a few related feature requests on Hydra's issue tracker: [hydra#1913](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1913) and [hydra#1983](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1983).

Comment: A fairly clunky workaround would be to create a file `conf/datamodule/my_trainer_settings.yaml` with a header `# @package _global_`. Adding the string `"my_trainer_settings"` to the defaults list of `conf/datamodule/my_datamodule.yaml` should then result in the desired output.